# How is the stack set up in a Windows function call?

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, stack

To begin, I'd like to say I have sufficient background in assembly to understand most of what one needs to know to be a functional assembly programmer. Unfortunately I do not understand how a Windows API call works in terms of the return address.

Here's some example code written in GAS assembly for Windows using MinGW's as as the assembler and MinGW's ld as the linker...

```
    .extern _ExitProcess@4
    .text
    .globl _main
_main:
     pushl $0
     call _ExitProcess@4
```

This code compiles and runs after assembling...

```
as program.s -o program.o
```

And linking it...

```
ld program.o -o program.exe -lkernel32
```

From my understanding, Windows API calls take arguments via push instructions, as can be seen above. Then during the call;

```
call _ExitProcess@4
```

the return address for the function is placed on the stack. Then, and this is where I'm confused, the function pops all the arguments off the stack.

I am confused because, since the stack is last in first out, in my mind while popping the arguments on the stack it would pop off the return address first. The arguments came first and the return address came next so it would technically be popped off first.

My question is, what does the layout of the stack look like after passing arguments via push operations to the function call and the return address placed on the stack? How are the arguments and the return address popped off the stack by the function as it executes? And finally, how is the return address popped off the stack and the function call rerturns to the address specified in the return addresss?

Comment: Bad example, ExitProcess() should not return at all.

Comment: It doesn't return a value, but it has a return address on the stack. When it returns with the ret instruction (\xc3 last I checked) it pops the return value off of the stack and directs execution flow to the Windows API before again directing execution to the next instruction after the call instruction that began the function call in the first place.

Comment: As Turbo J said, ExitProcess never returns. There's a return address on the stack, but it's never used and the function never executes a RET instruction. As the name of the function says, the function causes the process to exit which means it can't return to the caller because the caller will no longer exist.

Comment: Oh sorry my bad you're right. Try GetStdHandle, that's a palatable function. It takes a single argument pushed to the stack and does in fact return.

Answer (score 8):

Almost all Windows API functions use the [stdcall calling convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx).  This works like the normal "cdecl" convention, except as you've seen the called function is responsible for removing the argument when it returns. It does this using the RET instruction, which takes an optional immediate operand. This operand is the number of bytes to pop off the stack after first popping off the return value.

In both the cdecl and stdcall calling convention the arguments to a function aren't popped off the stack while the function is executing. They're left on the stack and accessed using ESP or EBP relative addressing. So when ExitProcess needs to access its argument it uses an instruction like `mov 4(%esp), %eax` or `mov 4(%ebp), %eax`.

Comment: No I mean if the function's arguments were pushed onto the stack before the return address, how can the function pop off the arguments without popping off the return address first?

Comment: @August It doesn't pop off the arguments until it returns.

Comment: Ah so it would pop the return address and then afterward pop the arguments off before it returns?

Comment: @August It does all that when it returns. The RET instruction pops the return address of the stack, sets the instruction pointer (EIP) to that return address, and then pops the arguments off the stack.

Comment: I think the word "pop" is misleading, hence the confusion. "ret" doesn't actually "pop" anything TO anywhere like "pop eax" instruction does (besides "popping" the return address of course.). It just increments the stack pointer by the immediate operand.

Comment: @August check details of the [`RET imm16`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_280.html) variant.